Calculating hyperbolic Fourier series
Question:

is it possible to uniquely express functions locally as infinite sums of hyperbolic sines and cosines
$f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \alpha_i\sinh(i\cdot x)+\beta_i\cosh(i\cdot x)$
or even in combination with the ordinary trigonometric functions  $f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \alpha_i\sinh(i\cdot x)+\beta_i\cosh(i\cdot x)+\gamma_i\sin(i\cdot x)+\delta_i\cos(i\cdot x)$
and what of ordinary Fourier analysis could be reused to calculate the coefficients?


Looks more like the discrete Laplace transform, a.k.a. the Z-transform, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform.
